# CSS Editing in Magento

Tags: custom, css

I'm new to Magento, with very little coding background to boot. I was hoping for some general direction with CSS customization.

I'm learning to add custom CSS rules that don't affect the default theme I have loaded into Magento. Currently, I understand that process as adding rules, via ftp, to *custom.css* within the theme's css directory.

Is this considered good practice within Magento?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well welcome to Magento!

First, I would read this PDF from Magento about Designing a theme.

- http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/MagentoDesignGuide.pdf

In regards to your question. In your local.xml (app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGENAME/YOURTHEMENAME/layout/local.xml) you will need to add something like this:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>custom.css</stylesheet></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Next, create your custom.css here: skin/frontend/YOURPACKAGENAME/YOURTHEMENAME/css

I would create your own theme (the PDF will help) rather then editing the base/default. The PDF will show you how to set it up.

Word of advice, it will take awhile to figure everything out. I have been working with Magento for 5 years everyday and I still learn new things. I would also learn version control. Version control is your friend and does take a while to figure out now, however you will save yourself time down the road.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. I certainly appreciate the magnitude of learning Magento, and fully expect to still be learning years down the road.

Comment: @kab8609 if you don't mind me asking. How did you start your career with Magento? From your answer, it seems you are working with Magento for 8 years already. I'm just curious how did you learn it? How did you start? 
How long did it take you to grasp something at the beginning? Your answer will mean a lot. Thanks.